# Drupal 7.50 : Class not found error after updating drupal

Tags: php, drupal, classnotfound

So I recently updated  my Drupal website from 7.1x to 7.50 (PHP 5.6) , now one of my custom modules doesn't work correctly, I get this error :

> Fatal error: Class 'RESTServerViewBuiltIn' not found in C:\Path\moduleName.views.inc on line 11.

I get this error only on one page, the website works correctly on the others

The error is at this line :

```
class RESTServerViewBuiltInCustom extends RESTServerViewBuiltIn {
```

The class `RESTServerViewBuiltInCustom` comes from the `REST server` module (so an external module), and this module is enabled.

Updating the website (`Admin > Update`) didn't solve the problem.

Also clearing the registry  didn't solve it either (I also checked the paths in the `registry` table and all paths are correct).

Can someone help me to solve this problem? What could be the causes of this error?

Comment: I'm feeling stupid right now, but really stupid, the class `RESTServerViewBuiltIn` in the `registry` table was missing, I checked the wrong database... I inserted the line `RESTServerViewBuiltIn` in the `registry` table and it works now.

Comment: Mark as solved please.

Comment: Hi.  I know you've already solved your issue, but posting here for future reference.  

Rather than inserting the entry into the table, you can use drush in conjunction with the registry rebuild command.  Admittedly, sometimes bootstrapping drush itself could fail if your registry is broken, but the following link helps with that too.

https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, the class `RESTServerViewBuiltIn` in the `registry` table was missing.

I inserted the line `RESTServerViewBuiltIn` in the `registry` table and it works now.